# Android Button with same width and height?

Tags: java, android, button

I am making a tic-tac-toe game, and I need to make the width and height of my buttons the same.

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" ...>

    <TextView
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tic-Tac-Toe" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cell_00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cell_10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cell_20"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--previous linear layout repeats twice more-->

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my activity:

```
// imports
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class TicTacToeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SIZE = 3;

    @BindView(R.id.game_feedback)
    TextView gameFeedback;

    private Button[][] grid = new Button[SIZE][SIZE];
    private int[][] cell_ids = {
            {R.id.cell_00, R.id.cell_01, R.id.cell_02},
            {R.id.cell_10, R.id.cell_11, R.id.cell_12},
            {R.id.cell_20, R.id.cell_21, R.id.cell_22}
    };

    private Button getButtonById(int id) {
        return (Button) findViewById(id);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        gameFeedback.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        loadGridButtons();

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell_00);
        int size = button.getLayoutParams().width;
        button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, size));
    }

    private void loadGridButtons() {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                grid[i][i] = getButtonById(cell_ids[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following error that crashes my app.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.mathsistor.m.tictactoe, PID: 20927
>                                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `button.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, size));` use `button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(size, size));`

**UPDATE**
Change `(size, size)` to `(SIZE, SIZE)` if that is the variable you are using. Otherwise, replace the variable with whatever size you want.

**UPDATE 2**

To get the width of the screen and divide it by 3, you can do this:
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int buttonwidth = (int) (size.x / 3);

Then you simply pass that variable instead of `SIZE` like so:

```
button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(buttonwidth, buttonwidth));
```

Comment: this is not working. Although now my app does not crash, width and height of the buttons are not the same.

Comment: this is working. However, what in the end I wanted was to read the screen width and take the third part as the width of my button, but thank you. Your answer solves my question.

Comment: I updated my answer again to help you with getting the screen width and dividing it by 3.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128311/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-sub-6-resources).